# Typescript error: Cannot read property X of undefined

Tags: typescript

i created an instance of class Meetings:

```
export var meeting: Meetings; //create a meeting instance of Meeting class present into meeting.ts
```

and when i call a function called "meetForMe()" on Meetings class:

```
var myMeeting = meeting.meetForMe(email);
```

i receive this error:

```
Cannot read property 'meetForMe' of undefined
```

I have declared class Meetings in this way:

```
export class Meetings{....}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Object shoud be created before it can be used:

```
export var meeting = new Meetings();
```

In your code you just declare a variable of "Meetings" type.

Comment: Perfect it work! I don't understand because on typescript format it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't initialized the `meeting` variable yet. Try `export var meeting: Meetings = new Meetings();` instead